# Getting dataframe with the absoulute difference between other two

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, difference

I have a dataframe like the following

```
    A   B   C
1   10  20  30
2   40  50  60
3   70  80  90
```

And another datraframe like the following:

```
    A   B   C
1   10  21  30
2   40  50  60
3   65  80  95
```

I need a dataframe like that:

```
    A   B   C
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   0
3   5   0   5
```

Showing the absolute diference between the original dataframes.
How can I get it?

Comment: use: `df1.sub(df2).abs()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.sub()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with [`df.abs()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html):

```
df1.sub(df2).abs()
```

---

```
    A   B   C
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   0
3   5   0   5
```

Answer (score 1):

`vanilla python` solution using `abs`:

```
abs(df1-df2)
```

```
   A  B  C
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
3  5  0  5
```

---

Or `numpy` method, using `np.substract` & `np.abs`

```
np.abs(np.subtract(df1, df2))
```

```
   A  B  C
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
3  5  0  5
```